# Add number to cell with alphanumeric value

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a column like this:

```
XL - 42
XXL - 44
XXL - 44
XL - 42
XL - 42
L - 40
M - 38
XXL - 44
XXL - 44
XL - 42
XXL - 44
XL - 42
XL - 42
L - 40
L - 40
XL - 42
XL - 42
XL - 42
L - 40
```

I want to add `"2"` to every number in the column - so in the first row, `XL - 42` should become `XL - 44`.

How do I do this on Microsoft Excel? Or Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2):

Please try (copied down to suit):

```
=index(split(A1,"-"),1)&" - "&index(split(A1,"-"),2)+2
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the numbers at right are 2 digits you can use in Excel, if A1 is your first Data in B1:
`=IF(A1<>"",SUBSTITUTE(A1,RIGHT(A1,2),RIGHT(A1,2)+2),"")`
and drag it down

- Right will read 2 digits example 40
- Substitute will replace the 2 digits with 2 digits+2 (40+2=42)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to break the column to two separate columns, one with the letters and the other with numbers, add +2 to every number, then merge the columns again.

The other way
As I can see these are all sizes. Then create two columns like this:

```
M - 38    M - 40
L - 40    L - 42
XL - 42   XL - 44
```

and so on, but only once per each replacement.

Then use VLOOKUP in a cell next to the original column, and then copy +paste (ONLY VALUE) from this second column to the original.

Answer (score 0):

For Excel:

Select only the cells you wish to process and run this short macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range, ary
    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Value, " - ")
        r.Value = ary(0) & " - " & CInt(ary(1)) + 2
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

A simple formula like this should work.

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1) & MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+2,2)+2
```

and then drag this down to the end. I put this forumula in B1 and then dragged it down. Here A1 is your first observation in the column A.

```
My output:-
    A         B
XL - 42     XL - 44
XXL - 44    XXL - 46
-----
-----
```

Let me know if you hae any questions around this.

Comment: @pnuts fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

For Google sheets:

`=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(A1:A19," - ")),
"select Col1, ' - ', Col2+2 label Col1 '', ' - ' '', Col2+2 ''")),,500))`

A bit long, but:

1. This is an ArrayFormula & no need to drag it down
2. It uses original range only once, so it's easier to modify.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, here's an alternative approach (also an arrayformula) for a google spreadsheet:

```
=ArrayFormula(regexextract(A1:A19, "\w+")&" - "& regexextract(A1:A19, "\d+")+2)
```